# Android Layout fails to open

Tags: java, android

I have this code in one of the java file of my application.

```
public class Board_Play1 extends Activity {

int d,a=0,b=0,turn=2;
Random random = new Random();
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.board_play1);
    while(a!=100 && b!=100)
    {
        if(turn%2==0)
        {
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
                    EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));

                }
            }); 
        }turn++;
    }

}


}
```

I come to this java file from another java file. All the problem I get is when this file doesn't have any while loop as in code it runs fine. But with including the while loop on navigating to this layout turns screen black and no further process can be done. If we press back button we have a pop out message saying `Your application isn't responding`. `Do You want to close?` `Yes No`.

Why is that happening. All things I included in while loop are perfect. What is causing for this problem?

Comment: It is infinite loop, freezing your app to death.

Comment: doesn't that let the application run till the user turns it off?

Comment: @vinaykumar what do you mean?

Comment: @vinaykumar no, since you are doing this on main (alternatively, UI) thread. Basically what's s4m0k answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an infinite loop. the condition in your while loop is always true because a and b values are never incremented.

And the reason why you're seeing black screen is that this infinite loop is blocking the Main UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is an infinite loop to me.

```
int a=0, b=0;
```

These values never change in your code and you are using them in your while loop's conditional.

Try something like:

```
while(a!=100 && b!=100)
{
    if(turn%2==0)
    {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
                EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));
            }
        }); 
    }

    turn++;

    // a = somevalue based on what you're trying to do.
    // b = somevalue based on what you're trying to do.
}
```